# SQL Server Database Project

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I want to use database project for script deployment in Azure SQL Server, I don't want to import full database. I just want to use database project for delta script. I added a project and included one script file with none as build action that contains create table statement , I am publishing the project, It's completing successfully but create statement is not executing. What is wrong here? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Set your build action to "Post Deployment Script".

Longer:

What happens in SSDT is that all the files that have a build action of "Build" are built into a model of what the database should look like. When the deploy happens that model is compared to the target database and if there are any changes, a change script it generated and then optionally deployed.

If you have any file marked pre or post deployment script then they are either prepended or appended to the change script and will be run as part of the deployment.

If you have any files with a build action of "None" then SSDT ignores them, you could put anything in there, even an ascii picture of a donkey and the project will still build and deploy (obviously your ascii donkey won't get deployed anywhere).

If you just want to use SSDT to do your deployments you can just set the build action to pre or post deploy and it will be included. This is pretty odd though, either don't use SSDT or use SSDT and put the model of your entire database in there.

Personally, I would use SSDT properly and live the dream.

Ed

Comment: thanks for the reply. Since I want to include only delta scripts, Shall I include all the scripts in post deployment scripts?, Since we can have only one post deployment script in a project. Can't we have multiple scripts files?

Comment: You can add the scripts with a build action of none then include them using ":r file.sql" into the single post-deploy script. You don't need to use SSDT to do what you are doing, just run your scripts and forget about SSDT

Comment: I want to use that scripts in multiple environment. Daily there will be a build. I don't want to execute each and every time. I just want to make changes in dacpac and keep in repository so that automatic deployment will take care of it. I don't know whether it's good approach or not. Below are my requirements.

Comment: Product is in live, will be adding more features in it. So we will be making lot of changes and create more tables in it. We have dev,into,qa , stage and production environment. I want to do the changes only in dev environment and rest of the environment has to be taken care by Dacpac. Please suggest me the best way to do it.

Comment: if you just want to write migration scripts then look at readyroll or dbup or something